# How to get a Producer Class to Make Map<String, Object> Results?

Tags: java

I have a QueryResults class with a method declared like this, that produces the results in one of many possible forms:

```
public <T> List<T> allRowsAs(Class<T> target)
```

I would like to get the results as a List of Map<String, Object> instances. This should be possible.

This seems like it should work, but it won't even compile:

```
QueryResult result = ...
List<Map<String, Object>> results = result.allRowsAs(Map<String,Object>.class);
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear and too broad. Each map should map the column name (`String`) to the column value?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @JohanLarson You have to pass ```Map.class```. It cannot be typed. At least not to my knowledge

Comment: Question is: why do you need a row as `Map<String, Object>`? Wouldn't it be easier to map the whole row to a java object through, e.g., JPA?

Comment: I'm trying to adapt existing code without a wholesale rewrite. In particular, I'd be reluctant to change the output format here from List<Map<String, Object>>.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `Map.class` to `allRowsAs` may or may not work, depending on how clever `allRowsAs` is.

It's possible that the function is using reflection to enumerate the members/properties of the class you pass in, instantiating the class for each row using `Class.newInstance`, and then populating each instance from the results. In this case, it will fail miserably with `Map`, because, first, Map has no properties that can be populated through reflection, and second, `Map` is an interface, not a class that can be instantiated.

So the function would pretty much have to have a special case for `Map`, and assume that you want a `HashMap<String, Object>` and not something else. It's more likely that if the `QueryResult` class supports this, it's a separate function, like `allRowsAsMaps` or something like that.

You might also look for a way to return rows as JSON object of some kind (GSON or Jackson or whatever). It sounds like that's really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Map<String,Object>.class` is not a valid class reference because
Classes suffixed with generics(`<..>`) are not valid class variables.
You could do that :

```
result.allRowsAs(Map.class);
```

And you should also define `allRowsAs()` to return `List<? extends T>`  :

```
public <T> List<? extends T> allRowsAs(Class<T> target){...}
```

But that will produce a raw type warning as `Map` is a generic class and you should also add a unchecked cast to `List<Map<String, Object>>` such as :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>) result.allRowsAs(Map.class);
```

That is definitively not the way to follow : unchecked cast, very verbose code in the client side.

As alternative you could defined a method specific to that requirement  :

```
public <T, U> List<Map<T, U>> allRowsAsMap() {

   // use the map that has rows
   Map<String, Integer> map = ...;
   // cast it to Map<T,U> : not safe but not choice in these conditions
   list.add((Map<T, U>) map);
}
```

And you could use it :

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = allRowsAsMap();
```

But in this way like in your original code, I think that you don't use the generics as you should.
Generics are designed to offer **genericity** and  **type safety**.
Here you don't benefit from type safety and the genericity is in a some way defeated since you don't know what you manipulate really.
In your case you should probably not use scoped method generic but using generic types with parameter types known in advance :

```
public  List<Map<String, Integer>> allRowsAsMap() {...}
```

That is less "sexy" but that is more robust : no cast and you know what you manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Generics has it's limitations. See there:
[Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)

Use this instead:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> allRowsAsMapList(){}
```